# Remove the end of a string with a varying string length using PHP

Tags: php, regex

Using PHP I have an array that return this data for an image:

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://website.dev/2014/05/my-file-name-here-710x557.png
    [1] => 710
    [2] => 557
    [3] => 1
)
```

Based on the demo data above, I need to somehow turn this image URL into:

`http://website.dev/2014/05/my-file-name-here.png` removing the `-710x557` from the string.

Some things to keep in mind are:

1. The file extension can change and be any type of file type
2. 710x557 might not ALWAYS be a 3 digit x 3 digit number. It could be 2 or 4

The reason I mention this is to show I cannot simply use PHP's string functions to remove the last **12** characters in the string and then add the file extension back because the last string characters could possibly be between 10 and 14 characters long sometimes and not always 12.

I was hoping to avoid a heavy regular expression code but if that is the only or best way here then I say go with it.

How do I write a regex that removes the end of a string that could have a varying length in PHP?

Comment: @PeeHaa he didn't say it _would_ be heavy, but some regexes can be heavy. And for a PHP newbie, even relatively short regexes may look scary and heavy. What's that expression... "Solving a problem with regex means you now have two problems"

Comment: The meta discussion surrounding this question is [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270586).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
-\d+x\d+(\.\w+)$
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/iE5kW3/4)**

[image]

The code you can use is:

```
$re = "/-\\d+x\\d+(\\.\\w+)$/"; 
$str = "http://website.dev/2014/05/my-file-name-here-710x557.png"; 
$subst = '\1'; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str, 1);
```

The idea is to match the resolution `-NumbersXNumbers` using `-\d+x\d+` (that we'll get rid of it) and then capture the file extension by using `(\.\w+)$` using capturing group. Check the substitution section above.

Comment: @Fede because you're probably helping a helpvampire? Also try to not mix double quotes and single quotes. Be consistent. I would use single quotes that way I wouldn't need to escape the backslashes `\d`.

Comment: So, am I being downvoted because I'm helping people? Downvotes are when an answer is not useful. Nice philosophy...

Comment: Helping people? [Read this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252868), I've ranted a bit about it. TLDR: you're not helping anyone in the long run.

Comment: @HamZa actually it's a nice post and I agree with some parts. Maybe SO should create a branch for regex. Btw, as I said, answer downvotes are when answers aren't useful, I don't consider that for mine.

Comment: @HamZa That's just rubbish. I don't see any reason why we should "punish" people that help someone with their problem, full stop. If you have a problem with the question, there are other avenues. And as this is the accepted answer and is a pretty well formulated answer it has clearly *already* helped someone and can't "not help anyone in the long run". This is just a misplaced vendetta in my opinion.

Comment: @Thor84no if you answer a question that does not show any (research) efforts. You're basically encouraging this bad behaviour. Some people tend to "punish" both questioner and answerer. As a side note: I did not upvote nor downvote this answer since I feel wrong about "punishing" someone that "just wants to help someone else". Although I must admit that I sometimes did downvote some answers because some people spoon feed every helpvampire they encounter and encourage this behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

As long as it is 2 sets of digits with an 'x' in the middle preceded by a dash you can use this regex:

```
-[\d]*x[\d]*

$string = 'http://website.dev/2014/05/my-file-name-here-710x557.png';
$pattern = '/-[\d]*x[\d]*/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/eh40-6d1x

Comment: The extension check and $ needs to be present otherwise things will get very broken - what if the filename is like: `MyCool1024x1024Photo-710x557.png` and you should be using `+` (at least one) not `*` (meaning 0 or more)

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) in the following manner to do this:

```
$str = substr($str, 0, strrpos($str, '-')) . substr($str, strrpos($str, '.'));
```

Comment: strrpos will always return the last occurance of a substring in a string. So as long as the dash before the dimensions is the last one in the string, this should work.

Comment: What if there is not a dash?

Comment: It will not work if there is not a dash. I have assumed that the structure of the filename is always something-WxH.(png|gif|jpg).

Answer (score 1):

```
$newsrc = preg_replace('#\-\d+x\d+(\.\w+$)#', '$1', $arr[0]);
```

see http://ideone.com/ZsELQ0

Comment: where is this condition `It could be 2 or 4`

Comment: or... what if the size is smaller than 10x10? It becomes a one digit x one digit

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex based code:

```
$str = "http://website.dev/2014/05/my-file-name-here-710x557.png"; 
$re = '/-([^-]+)(?=\.[^-]*$)/'; 

$result = preg_replace($re, '', $str, 1);
//=> http://website.dev/2014/05/my-file-name-here.png
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aQ3pY4/2)

Comment: Is the downvote only because problem was relatively simple or on the merit of the answer?

Comment: @anubhava , yes, the downvote was **only** because you are answering an extremely trivial question. As a top100 member of SO, you should be focusing on questions, that require expertise and insight. Not some "plz wrait regexp 4 me" posts.

Comment: @anubhava you might [read this](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/18408863#18408863). As always your intentions might be clean but you aren't helping the OP in the long run.